# Merge two array of objects by ID?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have following arrays of objects

```
firstAry = [{
    "status": "Creating",
    "datacenter-id": "1test",
    "datacenter-name": "1name"
}, {
    "status": "Creating",
    "datacenter-id": "2test",
    "datacenter-name": "2name"
}, {
    "status": "Creating",
    "datacenter-id": "id1",
    "datacenter-name": "data6"
}, {
    "status": "Creating",
    "datacenter-id": "id2",
    "datacenter-name": "data7"
}]
```

```
secondAry = [
  {
    "status": "Creating",
    "cluster-id": "1test",
    "cluster-name": "clu1",
    "datacenter-id": "null"
  },
  {
    "status": "Creating",
    "cluster-id": "1test1",
    "cluster-name": "clu1",
    "datacenter-id": "id1"
  },
  {
    "status": "Creating",
    "cluster-id": "1test113",
    "cluster-name": "clu11",
    "datacenter-id": "id1"
  },
  {
    "status": "Creating",
    "cluster-id": "2test2",
    "cluster-name": "clu2",
    "datacenter-id": "id2"
  },
  {
    "status": "Creating",
    "cluster-id": "2test22",
    "cluster-name": "clu22",
    "datacenter-id": "id2"
  }
]
```

I want to display 3 fields in the table - `status`, `cluster-name`, and `datacenter-name` in the table. The problem is I'm getting `status`, `cluster-name` in `secondAry` but the `datacenter-name` is getting in the `firstAry`. So I want to merge these two arrays on the basis of `datacenter-id`. If no matching `datacenter-id` then should display `datacenter-name` field as blank. I want to add the `datacenter-name` in the `secondAry` by matching id in `firstAry` and get `datacenter-name` field and add it in the `secondAry`.

Resulting array of object should be like this

```
Result = [   
{     "status": "Creating",     "cluster-id": "1test",     "cluster-name": "clu1",     "datacenter-id": "null" ,"datacenter-name": "null"  },   
{     "status": "Creating",     "cluster-id": "1test1",     "cluster-name": "clu1",     "datacenter-id": "id1", "datacenter-name": "data6"    },   
{     "status": "Creating",     "cluster-id": "1test113",     "cluster-name": "clu11",     "datacenter-id": "id1" , "datacenter-name": "data6"   },   
{     "status": "Creating",     "cluster-id": "2test2",     "cluster-name": "clu2",     "datacenter-id": "id2" ,"datacenter-name": "data7" },   
{     "status": "Creating",     "cluster-id": "2test22",     "cluster-name": "clu22",     "datacenter-id": "id2"  ,"datacenter-name": "data7" } ]
```

I tried filter method but its removing the element with no matching id. Kindly help how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.secondAry.forEach(x=>{
   const data=this.firstAry.find(f=>f['datacenter-id']==x['datacenter-id'])
   x['datacenter-name']=data?data['datacenter-name']:''
})
```

NOTE: it's would prefer use camelCase notation before using a "-". When use a "-" you need access to the property using `obj['property']`, else is simpe `obj.property`

Answer (score 0):

Find the matching objects from first array by comparing it with second array. Modify the result and return a new modified array.

```
const result = secondAry.map(item => {
const searchedItem = firstAry.find(fItem => fItem['datacenter-id'] === 
item['datacenter-id'] );
if(searchedItem && Object.keys(searchedItem).length > 0 ){
  item['datacenter-name'] = searchedItem['datacenter-name']
}else{
   item['datacenter-name'] = 'null'
}
 return item;
});

console.log(result);
```